# Запись Формулы PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

Как правильно записывать формулы в python?

```
(x+5)**2

a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2
```

В black каждый оператор имеет два пробела `a + b * 2`

Comment: Ну да, в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: А, [понятно в чём проблема](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations): «If operators with different priorities are used, consider adding whitespace around the operators with the lowest priority(ies).» Ну а поведение black описано [тут](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#line-breaks-binary-operators)

Comment: Никакого "правильно" нет, есть некоторый набор стилей написания кода. У создателей black и pep8 немного разные представления о прекрасном, так что в общем случае скорее всего не получится, чтобы было автоформатирование с помощью black, и чтобы все строго соответствовало pep8. Так что придется просто определиться, какому стилю вы следуете, там где стили не совпадают - игнорировать.